# ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved: error installing package in Julia

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to install julia Flux using pkg add and am getting the following error,

```
    julia> Pkg.add("Flux")
    ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
    * Flux (not found in project, manifest or registry)
    Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
   Stacktrace:
 

    [1] pkgerror(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Types.jl:120
     [2] #ensure_resolved#43(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Types.jl:900
     [3] #ensure_resolved at ./none:0 [inlined]
     [4] #add_or_develop#15(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:64
     [5] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
     [6] #add_or_develop#14 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:34 [inlined]
     [7] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
     [8] #add_or_develop#11 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:33 [inlined]
     [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
     [10] #add_or_develop#10 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:32 [inlined]
     [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
     [12] #add#20 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:74 [inlined]
     [13] add(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/API.jl:74
     [14] top-level scope at none:0
```

I tried using the `] add https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl` but got the same error could anyone help please
I tries also adding other packages but similar error occurs and am thinking maybe it is an error with the julia env but am not sure so am not trying to mess with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, this type of error either means you have no internet connection (or are behind a firewall that is blocking connections by the package manager) or your `.julia` folder is corrupted.

In the second case the easiest thing to try is to delete `.julia` folder or set the system variable `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` to point to some empty folder and restart Julia.

Comment: deleting .julia worked possibly was corrupted thanks

Comment: problem solved by deleting .julia. Possible version incompatibility issue?

Comment: what do you mean by deleting .julia folder? It is a huge folder with so many files. Should I delete it all?

Comment: yes and then reinstall Julia packages. this the last resort solution but is known to always work